# Why clicked button is not translating the container?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, event-handling, click

I am trying to make use the button to translate the container. For some resason after the container goes up and then down when a click the button for the third time nothing hapens.This cycle repeats, so every third click is not behaving as intended.

On top within the class I have this declared

```
double windowHeight;
double historyContainerHideTranslation;
double historyContainerShowTranslation;
```

In the constructor I have

```
windowHeight = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;

historyContainerHideTranslation = windowHeight * .07;
historyContainerShowTranslation = windowHeight * -.11;

HistoryContainer.TranslationY = historyContainerHideTranslation;
```

And the Method...

```
void HistoryBtnHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("  before if height =>  " +   HistoryContainer.TranslationY);


    if (HistoryContainer.TranslationY == historyContainerHideTranslation)
    {
        HistoryContainer.TranslateTo(0, historyContainerShowTranslation, 250, Easing.SinOut);
        HistoryContainer.TranslationY = historyContainerShowTranslation;

        Console.WriteLine("if stmnt height +>  " + HistoryContainer.TranslationY);

        }
        else
        {
            HistoryContainer.TranslateTo(0, historyContainerHideTranslation, 250, Easing.SinIn);

            HistoryContainer.TranslationY = historyContainerHideTranslation;
            Console.WriteLine("else stmnt height +>  " + HistoryContainer.TranslationY);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("after stmts height +>  " + HistoryContainer.TranslationY);

}
```

Comment: Try to invoked the code in UI thread .

Comment: I must admit I am quite new to this stuff. What is the UI Thread??

Comment: You would better share your sample so that I can test it on my side :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing relational numbers, round each one using Math.Round() to specify how many digits after the decimal point you want to have. In this case,when numbers are rounded to one digit, they will be the same.